# Не работает AND в ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-spreadsheet

В таблице вариант c IF

`=ARRAYFORMULA(if(K2:K=L2:L,1,0))`

при работе с 2 столбцами работает. А при работе с 4 столбцами вариант IFS

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(AND(F2:F>H2:H, K2:K>L2:L),1,AND(F2:F>H2:H, K2:K<=L2:L),0))`

обрабатывает только первую строку, т.е. как формула массива не работает. В чем может быть ошибка? Или я хочу невозможного?)

Comment: Какой результат нужен? ===1. Сомневаюсь, что и первая формула нормально работает... В таком виде формула должна размножиться на весь диапазон строк. У Вас указаны все строки столбца... Похоже, покажет ошибку. Если хотите увидеть количество совпадений по столбцам, то результат полученного массива нужно суммировать.=== 2. Функция `And` в таком применении в формуле массива не работает. Чего ждете от формулы?

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш первоначальный ответ был мне полезен и решил мою проблему.

Comment: Ваш вопрос останется... Какая задача решалась? Вторая Ваша формула перегружена лишними условиями.

Answer (score 0):

`AND (И)` - *ИСТИНА*, если все входящие условия истинны. Результат работы - одно значение, Вам же нужно получить массив.

В формулах массива вместо операторов `AND (И), OR (ИЛИ)` следует применять умножение или суммирование условий:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM((условие1)*(условие2))) 'AND'
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM((условие1)+(условие2))) 'OR'
```

Без формулы массива

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(условие1),--(условие2))
```

Не нужно указывать ссылку на весь столбец, это лишние вычисления.